# Setup IP Address info from unsigned int in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, connection, server

I got in my code a problem about sending something.

I got for example 2 Server.

This is Server 1:

```
unsigned int ip = 19216821;
unsigned int port = 4000;

char str[0];
sprintf(str, "%d", ip);
if ((dest_he=gethostbyname(str)) == NULL) {  // get the host info
        herror("gethostbyname");
        exit(1);
}

dest_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
dest_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
dest_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)dest_he->h_addr);
memset(dest_addr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof dest_addr.sin_zero);
```

then i want to send my buffer to dest_addr

```
if(sendto(sockfd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer),0, (struct sockaddr *)&dest_addr ,sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage)) == -1){
        printf("error sending data\n");
        return -1;
}
```

but I still get sendto(..) == -1.

My other Server is still waiting for an answer.
Server 2:

```
if(recvfrom(sockfd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer),0, (struct sockaddr *)&rand_addr ,&addr_size) == -1){
        printf("error receiving data");
        return -1;
}
```

I think my problem is that i setup the dest_addr wrong or?

Comment: Perhaps you would like to allocate some memory for the host name string (instead of `char str[0]`)? Also, if you want to lookup an IPv4 address (something like 192.168.2.1), then you'll need to include the dots in the string (which means you'll have to implement a function to convert your `unsigned int` representation, something like `ip = (192<<24)|(168<<16)|(2<<8)|1; sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", (ip>>24)&0xff, (ip>>16)&0xff, (ip>>8)&0xff, ip&0xff)`).

Comment: @SleuthEye OH NICE. It works now if i instead put "localhost" in my gethostname instead of str. Is there a way i can convert a int into a string without this sprintf? I couldnt find something about it. And the str[0] is bothering me somehow. Do you know how I can make it dynamic instead of [0]? Or is [0] large enough?

Comment: `unsigned int ip = 19216821;` is not a good way to store `192.168.2.1` if that's what you mean

Comment: _is [0] large enough?_ **Never** is [0] large enough.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your title doesn't really match your description. Nevertheless I'll make my best to answer your question.

Basically, you're not using correctly the function `gethostbyname`. As the name says it gets the host by its name not address. Hence, a correct usage would be:

```
struct hostent *host = gethostbyname("localhost");
```

To copy the result to your `struct` you can use:

```
memcpy(&dest_addr.sin_addr, host->h_addr_list[0], host->h_length);
```

On the other hand, if you want to send a message to a known IP-Address you can use:

```
char *ip = "127.0.0.1"
inet_aton(ip , &dest_addr.sin_addr)
```

Other than that everything looks fine. There are plenty of examples online on how to use TCP, UDP or even RAW sockets. I hope this was the answer you were expecting.